# Is the "dc impedance" and ESR the same thing?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, supercapacitor, esr

In a super-capacitor, what is the *[DC Impedance](http://www.ebay.de/itm/5pcs-5-5V-4F-H-Type-Super-Farad-Capacitor-double-layer-capacitance-/291761451294?)*? Is it the same as *ESR* (Equivalent Series Resistance)?

Comment: ESR is AC impedance measured at one (or a few) standard frequencies. Ergo it cannot be the same as DC impedance.

Comment: "DC impedance" is just "resistance", if you ask me. Needs more background. Where did you find that word? give context!

Comment: "DC impedance" of any ideal capacitor is infinity.

Comment: @MarcusMüller-here is the link to capacitor's 'data sheet': http://www.ebay.de/itm/5pcs-5-5V-4F-H-Type-Super-Farad-Capacitor-double-layer-capacitance-/291761451294?

Comment: @MarcusMüller-In my case the DC impedance is 25 ohm. See link.